# How to download application from dreamspark without using Secure Download Manager

Tags: download, dreamspark

How do you download application from dreamspark without using Secure Download Manager.

I have Download Accelerator Plus and DownThemALL firefox addon installed on my computer and I would like to use either of those to download application from dreamspark.

Comment: [This thread](http://superuser.com/questions/47272/downloading-vs-2008-from-dreamspark-over-multiple-sessions) tells you how to resume downloads using the manager, and [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/90146/downloads-from-msdn-keep-getting-broken-any-alternatives) mentions an alternative.